# How do I connect a light before a 3way, followed by a 3way, then a light?

Tags: wiring

I now have power to 3way A, connected to 3way B, to a light. I want to add a light before 3way A.  Power comes to a junction box, then to 3way A.  A is at the bottom of a stairs and B is at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear a diagram and pictures would help. If you want to add a light to a 3 way set up the easiest way is to run a 2 wire of the same size as the others in the circuit from the existing switched light to your new one and connect the wires color to color.

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT do this without rewiring. This is a common request that most folks think is no problem. It simply cannot be done with your existing wiring.

The simplest thing is to get a wire from the existing light to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the new light to be switched with the 3ways? If you want it to be independent, no problem. If you want it to work in tandem with the other light, BIG problem - one perhaps best solved by the use of a "wireless switch".